# Is token still assigned to user when server shutdown?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

As above, is token still assigned to user when server is shutting down? 
**Use case**: user get token with 10 minutes expiration time, 30 seconds after user get authorized, server shutdowns. After 30 second server wakes up. Does user still authenticated with previously granted token ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That completely depends on the Authorization Server's implementation of the requested token. If the token is a self-contained token like a JWT, it would still validate. If the token is a "by-reference-style" token then it may still validate if the Authorization Server uses persistent storage for its tokens, otherwise it would no longer validate.